# Reference a C++ class from one Windows Phone Runtime Component project in another

Tags: c++, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have two Windows Phone Runtime Component projects (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1) which contain C++ classes:

- FooRuntimeComponent:

  - FooClass.cpp
  - FooClass.h
- BarRuntimeComponent:

  - BarClass.cpp
  - BarClass.h

I would like to call methods on a Foo object created in the Bar class.

**Foo.h:**

```
#pragma once

namespace FooRuntimeComponent
{
    public ref class FooClass sealed
    {
    public:
        FooClass();
    };
}
```

**FooClass.cpp:**

```
#include "FooClass.h"

using namespace FooRuntimeComponent;
using namespace Platform;

FooClass::FooClass()
{
}
```

**BarClass.cpp:**

```
#include "BarClass.h"
#include "FooClass.h"

using namespace BarRuntimeComponent;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace FooRuntimeComponent;

BarClass::BarClass()
{       
    FooClass^ foo = ref new FooClass();
}
```

If I try link Foo to Bar "traditionally" by specifying the FooRuntimeComponent.lib as an additional dependency and providing a path to the .lib, then I get the following compilation error for Bar:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass::FooClass(void)" (??0FooClass@FooRuntimeComponent@@Q$AAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl BarRuntimeComponent::BarClass::BarClass(void)" (??0BarClass@BarRuntimeComponent@@Q$AAA@XZ)
```

Running dumpbin.exe on the FooRuntimeComponent.lib yields:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.31101.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file FooRuntimeComponent.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

          FF .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
          20 .idata$6
```

I did noticed that runtime components produce a .winmd file. I have tried adding this .winmd as a reference to the Bar project, but then I get the following errors:

```
error C2011: 'FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass' : 'class' type redefinition
error C2027: use of undefined type 'FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass'
error C2027: use of undefined type 'FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2680: 'FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass ^' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'FooRuntimeComponent::FooClass ^' to 'int'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right click on your `BarRuntimeComponent (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)` project item (not the solution) and select `Add` > `References...`. Click the `Add New Reference...` button and then locate the `FooRuntimeComponent` project (if the foo project is in the same solution as the bar project, then you'll find the foo project under the `Solution` item on the left of the window). Make sure the foo project is checked, then click OK then OK again. You should now be able to use `FooClass` in your bar project. That's really all there is to it.

You might first need to undo any other references you may have done previously (like the .lib file you manually linked against). Also remove the `#include "FooClass.h"` line from your BarClass.cpp file. The compiler gets the types from the .winmd file.

Comment: This is what I have already done (see my last paragraph). I did also remove the FooRuntimeComponent.lib from the project settings "Additional dependencies", whilst included the FooRuntimeProject as a reference to the Bar project. However I end up with the errors as listed in my last code listing. Not sure how there is a "redefinition" of the class.

Comment: In your BarClass.cpp file, remove the`#include "FooClass.h"` line. It's not necessary or required.